# altair, how to create Multi-panel line Plot with Linked Brushing?

Tags: plot, interactive, altair

I am trying to modify this altair plot:
https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_linked_brush.html

I have modified the code replacing: mark_point() with mark_line().

I want any line (Europe, Japan, USA) who has at least 1 point highlighted in the interval area (right in the figure), to be completely highlighted in both panels. However the interval selection is not working correctly:
[image: Interactive selection not highlighting over plot]

The code:

```py
# from https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_linked_brush.html 
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

brush = alt.selection(type='interval', resolve='global')

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color=alt.condition(brush, 'Origin', alt.ColorValue('gray')),
).add_selection(
    brush
).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
)

base.encode(x='Horsepower') | base.encode(x='Acceleration')
```

I want to be able to highlight multiple lines across multiple panels.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do here – what do you expect to happen? If you highlight a line segment on one chart, what should be highlighted on the other chart? The line segments do not have a 1-1 mapping between panels because the points are in different orders, so it's not obvious to me what the "right" behavior is.

Comment: I Want all lines who have at least 1 point highlighted in the interval area, to be highlighted completely in both plots

Comment: That would require projecting the interval selection over the color's field, but unfortunately this is not supported in vega-lite: see https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/project.html#current-limitations

Comment: ok, thank you. it would be a great feature for them to add as a lot of data is displayed as a line and has multiple features